# Sniff Test: Lots of new users who all joined at the same time and are asking and answering each other's questions

Tags: discussion

A few days (3 at time of writing) ago we had several seemingly unrelated users join, they all seem to be asking questions relating to headaches/migraines and are answering each other's questions. The questions aren't flat out awful or spammy but they aren't particularly good either and the answers are generally low effort.

One of the users' profile link is to a poor quality wordpress blog, they aren't hiding their affiliation the username is the same as the site name but the rest of it all fairly reeks of sock-puppetry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it does look like sock puppetry. We're aware of these users and the stackexchange Community Moderation team is investigating. If you see any outright spam from them or you notice new sock puppets, please flag them.

Comment: We had a question on the Hot Network Questions List, maybe this is a reason.

Comment: @Narusan We now have 3 HNQs at the same time! That looks more like people realised how to game the algo?

Comment: May I suggest that these kind of Q&As get mod-removed from HNQ?

Comment: @LangLangC They seem to be gone now. No HNQs from MedSci that I can see.

Comment: I'll gladly remove them if they're not HNQ worthy. If you see another one, please flag it.

Comment: Will do. // Curiously on HNQ-SE they are gone, but on MedSci main there are stiil 3 flames (all of them per timeline once on HNQ; perhaps a bug in script or they are still eligible? Anyway, big list doesn't show them, so that's that.)

Comment: @LangLangC I went through the hot questions list and you're right, several apparently were on the HNQ at one time. They've now been permanently removed from it. I was wondering why all the answers from the (apparent) sock puppets and this may be why.